# Sphinx search gives no results

Tags: search, sphinx

I have a new index on a new table which is not returning any results.  This is very odd, and I've never run into this problem before.  Other indices (which are built almost identically) are searchable just fine from the search CLI and my API.

Here's my conf file

```
source topicalindex
{
  type            = pgsql
  sql_host        = localhost
  sql_user        = user
  sql_pass        = password
  sql_db          = db
  sql_port        = 5432  # optional, default is 3306
  sql_query       = SELECT id, topic, reference, start_ref, end_ref, see_also_html FROM my_topicalindex
  sql_attr_uint   = topic
  sql_attr_uint   = reference
}


index topicalindex_index
{
  source          = topicalindex
  path            = /path/to/data/topical_index
  docinfo         = extern
  charset_type    = utf-8
}

indexer
{
  mem_limit       = 32M
}

searchd
{
  listen          = 3312
  log             = /path/to/searchd.log
  query_log       = /path/to/query.log
  read_timeout    = 5
  max_children    = 30
  pid_file        = /usr/local/var/searchd.pid
  max_matches     = 30000
  seamless_rotate = 1
  preopen_indexes = 0
  unlink_old      = 1
}
```

Here's a excerpt proving there's content in the DB

```
[myself]:myapp(master)$ psql -d mydb -h localhost
psql (9.2.2)
Type "help" for help.

esv=# SELECT * FROM my_topicalindex LIMIT 1;
  id  |  topic  |     reference      | start_ref | end_ref | see_also_html 
------+---------+--------------------+-----------+---------+---------------
 2810 | Abraham | Genesis chs. 11–25 |   1011001 | 1025034 | blank
(1 row)
```

Here's the indexing process:

```
$ indexer --rotate --all --config /path/to/sphinx-topical.conf
Sphinx 0.9.9-rc2 (r1785)
Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff

using config file '/path/to/sphinx-topical.conf'...
indexing index 'topicalindex_index'...
collected 2809 docs, 0.1 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 2809 docs, 75007 bytes
total 0.067 sec, 1117456 bytes/sec, 41848.54 docs/sec
total 3 reads, 0.000 sec, 47.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 7 writes, 0.000 sec, 37.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=79833).
```

And the files showing they have content

```
[myself]:myapp(master)$ ll /path/to/data/
total 160
drwxr-xr-x 10 myself admin   340 Aug 29 08:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 myself admin   102 Jun  1  2012 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 myself admin 33708 Aug 29 08:56 topical_index.spa
-rw-r--r--  1 myself admin 51538 Aug 29 08:56 topical_index.spd
-rw-r--r--  1 myself admin   326 Aug 29 08:56 topical_index.sph
-rw-r--r--  1 myself admin 15721 Aug 29 08:56 topical_index.spi
-rw-r--r--  1 myself admin     0 Aug 29 08:56 topical_index.spk
-rw-------  1 myself admin     0 Aug 29 08:56 topical_index.spl
-rw-r--r--  1 myself admin     0 Aug 29 08:56 topical_index.spm
-rw-r--r--  1 myself admin 52490 Aug 29 08:56 topical_index.spp
```

and then -- my search with 0 results

```
[myself]:myapp(master)$ search -i topicalindex_index -a "Abraham"
Sphinx 0.9.9-rc2 (r1785)
Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff

using config file '/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf'...
index 'topicalindex_index': query 'Abraham ': returned 0 matches of 0 total in 0.000 sec

words:
1. 'abraham': 0 documents, 0 hits
```

**Why am I getting 0 results when I search "Abraham".  (Strangely, I do get results when searching "a")

Is this a problem with my conf file?  Is it something else?**

**EDIT**
I've noticed that when searching "a" it is only searching against those rows which do have content for the see_also_html field.  The number of matches matches the count of fields which have data for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sql_query       = SELECT id, topic, reference, start_ref, end_ref, see_also_html FROM my_topicalindex
 sql_attr_uint   = topic
 sql_attr_uint   = reference

  id  |  topic  |     reference      | start_ref | end_ref | see_also_html 
------+---------+--------------------+-----------+---------+---------------
 2810 | Abraham | Genesis chs. 11–25 |   1011001 | 1025034 | blank
```

You've made `topic` and `reference` integer attributes. (So they **won't** be included as full-text fields)

Columns not made an attribute (excluding the first column!) are automatically fields.

So `start_ref`, `end_ref` and `see_also_html` will be full-text fields, and therefore searchable.

Answer (score 0):

OUT OF TOPIC ANSWER

Note:  for more readability in your file 
you can replace

```
sql_query       = SELECT id, topic, reference, start_ref, end_ref, see_also_html FROM my_topicalindex
```

by

```
sql_query       = SELECT id,             \
                         topic,          \
                         reference,      \
                         start_ref,      \
                         end_ref,        \
                         see_also_html   \
                    FROM my_topicalindex
```

Just be careful  \ would be the last character (not space)

Sample of statement where I'm happy to use this notation

```
sql_query        =                                                                              \
    SELECT        /* sphinx index article Video  */                                             \
    `article`.id                                    AS id,                                      \
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`article`.fromDate)              AS ressource_date,                          \
    unix_timestamp(now())                           AS indexing_date,                           \
    `programs`.id                                   AS emission_id,                             \
    IFnull(cat.parent_id, cat.id)                   AS genre_id,                                \
    `article`.`title`                               AS `title_str`,                             \
    `article`.`title`                               AS `title`,                                 \
    `article`.`feed`                                AS `feed_ordinal`,                          \
    `article`.`feed`                                AS `feed`,                                  \
    `article`.`category`                            AS `category`,                              \
    `article`.`dossierId`                           AS `dossierId`,                             \
    `article`.`mainImage`                           AS `mainImage`,                             \
    group_concat(`keywords`.`translation`)          AS `tags`,                                  \
    group_concat(o.id)                              AS `video_id_list`,                         \
    concat(' summary:',                                                                         \
            `article`.summary,                                                                  \
            ' synopsis',                                                                        \
            `article`.synopsis,                                                                 \
            ' Summary Title :',                                                                 \
            `article`.summaryTitle,                                                             \
            ' Url',                                                                             \
            `article`.title_url,                                                                \
            ' Main',                                                                            \
            `article`.mainParagraph)                AS content,                                 \
    concat( ' Signature:',                                                                      \
            `article`.signature)                    AS subcontent,                              \
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(article.fromDate)                AS online_from_date,                        \
    if ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(article.toDate)<2000000000,                                             \
         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(article.toDate),                                                        \
         2000000000)                                AS online_to_date                           \
FROM                                                                                            \
    `article`.`article`                                                                         \
LEFT JOIN                                                                                       \
    `media`.`programs`                                                                          \
ON                                                                                              \
    `article`.`category` = `programs`.`articleReferenceCategory`                                \
LEFT JOIN                                                                                       \
    `media`.`category` AS cat                                                                   \
ON `programs`.mainCategoryId = cat.id                                                           \
LEFT JOIN                                                                                       \
    article.article_keyword                         AS ak                                       \
ON                                                                                              \
    ak.articleId = article.id                                                                   \
LEFT JOIN                                                                                       \
    article.keyword                                 AS keywords                                 \
ON                                                                                              \
    ak.keywordId = keywords.id                                                                  \
AND `keywords`.`visible`   = 1                                                                  \
AND `keywords`.`translation` !=''                                                               \
LEFT JOIN                                                                                       \
        article.embed                                          AS ae                            \
ON                                                                                              \
    ae.articleId = article.id                                                                   \
INNER JOIN                                                                                      \
    media.`objects`                                        AS o                                 \
ON                                                                                              \
    o.id = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING(ae.code, 5+LOCATE('rel="',ae.code)), '"', 1)              \
    AND  o.type='video'                                                                         \
    AND o.status='complete'                                                                   \
      AND o.active=1                                                                            \
      AND ( o.part_type IS NULL OR o.part_type = 'extract')                                     \
      AND o.wildcard not like 'www.%.be/presse%'                                             \
                                                                                                \
WHERE                                                                                           \
    `article`.`validated` = 1                                                                   \
AND `article`.`published` = 1                                                                   \
AND `article`.`deleted` = 0                                                                     \
AND `article`.`displayDate` < Now()                                                             \
AND `article`.`fromDate` < Now()                                                                \
AND `article`.`toDate` > Now()                                                                  \
AND `article`.id >= $start                                                                      \
AND `article`.id < $end                                                                         \
GROUP BY `article`.id
```

Comment: Correction: for LESS readability, you could replace it with that. All that extra whitespace and extraneous slashes, just confuse the matter, and make it harder to read. IMHO of course! ;p

Comment: Oh  you dislike it!
Just for example I dump a statement I can't read on "one line" perhaps  you see an improvement :-)

Comment: Thats just it, its subjective. Just like any tool, it can be used for good, but it can also be abused. Theres loads of things that could be done to that query that would optimize it for sphinx, but also to make it more readable. But as you you say its off topic.